# 2 out of 6 GTX 1060 not properly installed its driver, how can I fix it?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, gpu

I've bought 5 ZOTAC GTX 1060 3GB and 1 EVGA GTX 1060 3GB SUPERCLOCKED, by some random reason 2 of the 6 GPU refused to install properly, I downloaded the driver using Geforce Experience, it was NVIDIA's 384.94 driver, this following result:
[image: Device Manager]

After that, I've figured by hardware ID that EVGA was the third one from the list, and tried downloading from EVGA website its driver, which actually just made me download directly from NVIDIA, even so, I've installed it and the error continued.

I'm currently using Windows 10 x64bits, all the GPU are being recognized correctly and they are being extended by the use of Riser (a PCI express extender), here is a picture of one:
[image: Riser]

What can I do to fix it? (I've also tried individually asking windows to update the driver)

Comment: I seem to recall Windows 10 currently having a limit (8) to the number of GPUs it will actually register.  All your GPUs use the exact same driver, don't confused Windows, by using different versions of the same driver that WILL lead to instability.  Try installing each GPU one by one.  If they are all being recognized I am not sure what your question is exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to reduce resources in BIOS, each motherboard has different properties that can enable more PCI-E GPU, sometimes is a mining mode, in my case was to change TOLUD to 3.5GB, disabling VT-d, and putting PCI-E to GEN1