# GPUs aren't recognized by nvidia-smi

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia-graphics-card, hardware-detection

[Possible duplication](https://superuser.com/questions/1236654/2-out-of-6-gtx-1060-not-properly-installed-its-driver-how-can-i-fix-it), but that post is on MS window, mine is on Linux and I wasn't able to solve my problem reading that post.

Specs:

- Motherboard: [AsRock H170 Pro4/Hyper](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/H170%20Pro4Hyper/)
- CPU: [Intel G4400](https://ark.intel.com/de/products/88179/Intel-Pentium-Processor-G4400-3M-Cache-3_30-GHz)
- GPUs: 6 x Gigabytes GTX 1070
- PSU: Corsair 1500W
- OS: Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 LTS

Notes: this is a mining rig.

5 GPUs connected to motherboard through x1 PCIe risers, 6th GPU connect to motherboard through M2 slot. PCIe risers and GPUs aren't the problem because for any combination of 4 out of 6 cards. System operates as expected.

When all 6 cards are installed to motherboard,

```
lspci | grep -i vga
```

reports all 6 cards with busID from 1 through 6, but only 4 are detected by `nvidia-smi` and operate.

```
dmesg | grep -i  nvidia
```

reports this for the 2 cards not detected by smi (busID either 4 and 5, 5 and 6, or 4 and 6):

```
NVRM: This PCI I/O region assigned to your NVIDIA device is invalid:
```

So I thought my chipset doesn't have enough PCIe lanes and the M2's x4 took all the lane, but when I look up in Intel main page. Intel H170 chipset (my motherboards chipset) has 16 PCIe lanes. My 5 GPUs (x1), 2 of which use CPU lanes (the x8 and x16 slot), so 3 + 4 (the M2 slot) = 7 lanes taken from chipsets 16 PCIe lanes. Therefore, my motherboard should be able to handle 6 GPUs, right? How do I get it going?

Comment: Your motherboard’s firmware probably can’t handle all the mapped memory regions. // Please also provide the output of `lspci -v`

Comment: @DanielB, is there a way a can get through that ?? Well before considering buying another mobo. I've already updated the bios to the lastest version

Comment: No, there is no way. Your specifications are missing the amount of RAM.

Comment: It appears the output of `lspci -vvv` is required, my bad. You could try something like `lspci -vvv -d 10de:` to filter to NVIDIA devices.

Comment: wow, that's a lot of output :|

Comment: Yeah, so? If you’re afraid it’s too big for Super User, use a pastebin site.